# gdb on iPad failing to dump memory

Tags: ios, ipad, memory, gdb, dump

I'm attempting to look at the memory of an app running on my iPad. I've got the pid of the app and I'm able to attach to the process with `gdb`.

```
iPad:~/dev root# gdb -p 3839
GNU gdb 6.3.50.20050815-cvs (Fri May 20 08:08:42 UTC 2011)
Copyright 2004 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
GDB is free software, covered by the GNU General Public License, and you are
welcome to change it and/or distribute copies of it under certain conditions.
Type "show copying" to see the conditions.
There is absolutely no warranty for GDB.  Type "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "--host=arm-apple-darwin9 --target=".
/private/var/root/dev/3839: No such file or directory
Attaching to process 3839.
0x35824004 in ?? ()
(gdb)
```

However, when i attempt to dump one of the memory regions:

```
(gdb) info mach-regions
Region from 0x22000 to 0x24000 (---, max r-x; copy, private, not-reserved)
   ... from 0x24000 to 0x269000 (---, max r-x; copy, private, not-reserved)
[...]
   ... from 0x267a000 to 0x267b000 (---, max rwx; copy, private, not-reserved)
   ... from 0x267b000 to 0x267c000 (---, max rwx; copy, private, not-reserved)
   ... from 0x267c000 to 0x267d000 (---, max rwx; copy, private, not-reserved)
   ... from 0x267d000 to 0x267f000 (---, max rwx; copy, private, not-reserved)
   ... from 0x267f000 to 0x2680000 (---, max rwx; copy, private, not-reserved)
[...]
(gdb) dump binary memory output.bin 0x267c000 0x267d000
```

I get this error:

```
gdb stack crawl at point of internal error:
0   gdb                                 0x00170e74 internal_vproblem + 124
1   gdb                                 0x0016dd68 internal_verror + 52
2   gdb                                 0x0016dd94 align_down + 0
3   gdb                                 0x0016def8 gdb_check_fatal + 36
4   gdb                                 0x001eba9c mach_xfer_memory + 588
5   gdb                                 0x000c7ca8 default_xfer_partial + 256
6   gdb                                 0x000ca04c target_xfer_partial + 1004
7   gdb                                 0x000ca404 target_read_partial + 56
8   gdb                                 0x000ca488 target_read + 120
9   gdb                                 0x000ca674 target_read_memory + 68
10  gdb                                 0x00003f5c dump_memory_to_file + 276
11  gdb                                 0x0016c804 execute_command + 1160
12  gdb                                 0x000aba88 command_handler + 228
13  gdb                                 0x000acd94 command_line_handler + 768
14  gdb                                 0x002236b4 rl_callback_read_char + 160
../../gdb-1518/src/gdb/macosx/macosx-nat-mutils.c:772: internal-error: assertion failure in function "mach_xfer_memory": r_end >= cur_memaddr

A problem internal to GDB has been detected,
further debugging may prove unreliable.
Quit this debugging session? (y or n) y
```

At which point the app crashes as well, once I exit gdb.

It seems like I'm doing everything right, here... why is the error happening? And how would one go about making it work?

I'm running iOS 5.1.1 on the first generation iPad.

Comment: +1 for being awesome and using the debugger on the device (and anyway this might happen to me in the future, so it's helpful to know a possible solution).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ah apparently the version of GDB that ships with Cydia [doesn't work on iOS 5](http://www.securitylearn.net/tag/gdb-ios-5/). These instructions worked for me:

> GNU Debugger (gdb) is used to analyze the run time behavior of an iOS application. In recent iOS versions, GNU Debugger directly downloaded from the Cydia is broken and not functioning properly. Following the Pod 2g blog post also did not help me.
>
> To get rid of this problem, add http://cydia.radare.org to cydia source and download the latest GNU Debugger (build 1708). GDB build 1708 is working for iOS 5.x.

Comment: Thanks a trillion for this. I think the reason Pod2G's instructions don't work is because the first-gen iPad is an armv6 device, whereas the version of `gdb` he pulls out of Xcode is only compiled with armv7 support.